# Can I increase the screen dimming in Android v4?

Tags: screen

I've noticed that Android v4 on a Samsung Galaxy Note does not dim the screen nearly enough in darkness or very low light, even when the auto dimming feature is turned on.  Are there any controls I've missed?  Are there any applications that increase the screen dimming?

If not, can anyone make comments on trying to write such an application?  Would I need to modify Cyanogen to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the app [Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor), it does just what you need with no extra hassle.